# How to parse hours,minutes and seconds from a string to a TimeSpan object?

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan, string-formatting

I'm passing a string as a unit of time via a query string. But when I try to parse the string to a time span object I get a `System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code` which I gather means there is a problem with way I'm formatting the string to be parsed.

```
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("workTimeSpanPkr"))
            {
                testString = NavigationContext.QueryString["workTimeSpanPkr"];
                //Assign text box string value to a test time span variable.
                 testTm = TimeSpan.ParseExact(testString, @"hh\ \:\ mm\ \:\ ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            }
```

The string being passed over  `testString` when I run it through the debugger is: `"00:15:04"``

Does anyone know the correct format for parsing hours,minutes and seconds?

This is the value I'm trying to parse and the code I'm using to achieve this:

[image: format exception]

[image: value of work string]

Comment: Why all the escape sequences on a string literal (@)? sounds like the parse format should be `"hh:mm:ss"`.

Comment: is it really quoted like that?  - single, double, string, double, single, single - thats not right

Comment: With that simple of a parse you can probably just use `TimeSpan.Parse` or `TimeSpan.TryParse`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET A common mistake., DateTime and TimeSpan format are not the same. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @L.B Learn something new every day. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:15:04", @"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, TimeSpanStyles.None));
```

You should remove the whitespace from the format string if you want to match your example of `00:15:04`.

Also you may want to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I had originally been parsing an actual string as enetered in a textbox which is why the above formatting didn't work. The new string I'm passing over is of type TimeSpan so there is no white space which is where the problem was.The above solution worked,thanks

Comment: I re ran the code and I got a format exception again, strange.  This is how I'm parsing as per your example: `workTm = TimeSpan.ParseExact(wrkString, @"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, TimeSpanStyles.None);`

Comment: Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @BrianJ if it is happening that means your `wrkString` string is not what you claim it is. Post a screenshot of the string from the debugger.

Comment: Just added a screen shot from the debugger of the wrkString value.

Comment: Your query string value is being selected including the `=` for some reason.